# How to read string stored in hdf5 format files by DM

Tags: hdf5, typeconverter, dm-script

I am scripting with DM and would like to read hdf5 file format.

I borrowed Tore Niermann's gms_HDF5_Plug-In (hdf5_GMS2X_amd64.dll) and his CMD_import_hdf5.s script. It use h5_read_dataset(filename, datapath) to read a image dataset.

I am trying to figure out the way to read a string info stored in the same file. I am particular interested to read the angle stored in string as shown in this figure.[Demonstrated string to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekAd5.png). The h5_read_dataset(filename, datapath) function doesn't work for reading string.

There is a help file (hdf5_plugin.chm) with a list of functions but unfortunately I can't open them to see more info. 
[hdf5_plugin.chm showing the function list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8l3u.png).

I suppose the right function to read strings should be something like h5_read_attr() or h5_info() but I didn't test them out. DM always says the two functions doesn't exist.

After reading out the angle by string, I will also need a bit help to convert the string to a double datatype.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting String to Number is done with the `Val()` command.
There is no integer/double/float concept for variables in DM-script, all are just `number`. ( This is different for `images`, where you can define the numeric type. Also: For file-inport/export a type differntiation can be made using the taggroup streaming commands in the other answer. )

Example script:

```
string numStr = "1.234e-2"
number num = val( numStr )
ClearResults()
Result( "\n As string:" + numStr )
Result( "\n As value:" + num )
Result( "\n As value, formatted:" + Format(num,"%3.2f") )
```

Comment: Great. Val() is something I am looking for.  For the file-inport/export example, are you referring to “how-to-convert-ascii-array-image-to-a-single-string”https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719129/how-to-convert-ascii-array-image-to-a-single-string

Comment: Similar to that one, yes. But with the difference that you create your stream object from a file and then use taggroup-objects to read in (or write out) a certain number of bytes interpreted as the specific taggroup-type. That is the reason why the TagGroup has a lot of commands of form ...asLong  ...asDouble etc.

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer regarding the .chm files: When you download (or email) .chm files in Windows, the OS classifies them as "potentially dagerouse" (because it could contain executable HTML code, I think). As a result, these files can not be shown by default. However, you can right-click these files and "unblock" them in the file properties.

Example:
[image]

Comment: you are absolutely right. I can see the explanation after unblock it. Perfect

Answer (score 0):

> I think this will be most likely a question specific to that plugin and not general DM scripting. So it might be better to contact the plugin-author directly.

The alternative (not good) solution would be to "rewrite" your own HDF5 file-reader, if you know the file-format. For this you would need the "Streaming" commands of the DM script language and browse through the (binary?) source file to the apropriate file location. The starting point for reading on this in the F1 help documentation would be here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I contact the plugin-author and he made a updated plugin which can read string.  That is really helpful.